# Find the number of functions $4f^3(x)=13f(x)+6$

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

> $f(x)$ is a function satisfying
> $$4f^3(x)=13f(x)+6$$
> $\forall\ x\in [-3,3]$ and is discontinuous only and only at all integers in $[-3,3]$. If $N$ denotes the unit digit of the number of all such functions, find $N$.
>
> Answer: $6$.

Solving the cubic for $f(x)$ gives us
$$f(x)=-\frac{3}{2},-\frac{1}{2}\ \text{or}\ 2$$

Then I figured, for $f$ to be discontinuous at integers, we must define it piecewise(i.e casewise) on the integers, with the value of the function changing at integers.

Something like$f(x)=$
$$
\begin{cases}
 -0.5 & -3\leq x<-2 \\
 -1.5 & -2\leq x<-1 \\
 -0.5 & -1\leq x<0 \\
    2 &  0\leq x<1 \\
 -1.5 &  1\leq x<2 \\
 2 &  2\leq x<3 \\
 -1.5 &  x=3\\
\end{cases}
$$

So I thought, this problem is equivalent to filling $7$ blanks with $3$ distinct objects, and no two adjacent blanks contain the same object.

Hence, the first blank can be filled in $3$ ways, the second in $2$ ways, the third in $2$ ways and so on, until the seventh blank in $2$ ways.

So the number of ways is $$3\times2\times2\times2\times2\times2\times2=192$$
whose unit digit is not $6$.

> Could anyone tell me where I went wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the values in $-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3$ may also be different

Comment: @Exodd Hmm, hadn't considered that. That increases the number of blanks to $14$, with the number of $2$-blanks as $13$. So the answer is $3×8192$ which matches. Could you convert that into an answer so I can accept it? Thanks.

Comment: It is still wrong, since you have many more possibilities

Comment: @Exodd I'm unable to see. Could you please provide a complete answer?

Comment: I can't write a full answer rn, but notice that now you are not counting functions with $f[0,1)=2$

Comment: @Exodd Oh wow, I missed that completely. Please could you write a complete answer whenever you can?

Comment: Is it $f^3(x)=f(f(f(x)))$ or is it $f(x)^3$ as in the third power of the function value. You seem to have used the cubic interpretation, but was that also the intention of the task?

Comment: @Lutz Lehmann in this case, that is the intended one. If $f^3(x)$ would have stood for $f(f(f(x)))$,they would have mentioned it.

Comment: But it is the standard meaning, $f(x)^n$ is for the power, $f^n(x)$ for $(n-1)$ fold composition with itself and $f^{(n)}(x)$ for the $n$th derivative. So if they meant the power, they would have written $f(x)^3$. It only gets ambiguous if the argument is left out, $4f^3=13f+6$ could be read both ways.

Comment: @Lutz Lehmann I know, but I'm pretty sure of this, that cubic is the intended meaning. For the exam I'm studying, that is the "normal" assumption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that for each $x, f(x) \in \{-3/2,-1/2,2\}$.
Denoting Ride hand limit with RHL and Left hand limit with LHL

For $x=-3$, the discountinuity is when $f(-3) \neq RHL$.
So here $3*2=6$ values for f(-3) and RHL at x=-3 such that both aren't equal.

Now due to the above operation, RHL of x=-3 = LHL for x=-2 is fixed, as f(x) is continuous in (-3,-2)

So for x=-2, the only quantities that we haven't determined are f(-2) and RHL at x=-2. For discountinuity, atleast one of these must not be equal to RHL at x=-2. So a total of $3*3-1=8$ possibilities for f(-2) and RHL at x=-2.

Similarly x=-1,0,1,2 follow the same pattern as that of x=-2.

For $x=3$, the LHL is fixed, and the only way for discountinuity at this point is when $f(3) \neq LHL$ at x=3.
This can be done in 2 ways.

Hence a total of $6 \times 8^5 \times 2 = 3 \times 2^{17}$ functions.

And using basic number theory, we can calculate the unit digit of the above number to be $6$.

Answer (score 1):

The following are the properties that fully characterize your function $f$:

- For every $x$, $f(x)\in \{2,-1/2,-3/2\}$
- $f$ must be constant on every open interval $(n,n+1)$ for $n=-3,-2,-1,0,1,2$
- among $f(n-1,n)$, $f(n)$, $f(n,n+1)$ there must be at least two different values for $n=-2,-1,0,1,2$
- $f(3) \ne f(2,3)$, $f(-3)\ne f(-3,-2)$

As you did, you can start by fixing $f(-3)$ and $f(-3,-2)$ in 6 ways. Then you can fix $f(-2)$ and $f(-2,-1)$ in $6 + 2 =8$ ways. The same 8 ways for $f(-1)$ and $f(-1,0)$, etc.
The last choice is $f(3)$ that can be made in 2 ways.

For a total of $6\times 8^5\times 2$ ways. Since $2^5\equiv 2\pmod{10}$, we have $6\times 8^5\times 2 = 3 \times 2^{17}\equiv 3 \times 2^{5} \equiv  6\pmod {10}$

Comment: What is meant by $f(n,n+1)$?

Comment: @AryanSonwatikar The value of $f$ in the open interval $(n,n+1)$

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm unable to see why 8 ways. Please could you explain?